# ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0

Tags: linux, docker, elasticsearch

Using this website : https://logz.io/blog/elk-stack-on-docker/ to install elk. I am then sadly getting the following error ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0. When I run docker-compose up -d. The full output message is:

### Building elasticsearch
[+] Building 56.3s (3/3) FINISHED
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                               0.2s
=> => transferring dockerfile: 263B                                                               0.0s
=> [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                  0.3s
=> => transferring context: 2B                                                                    0.0s
=> ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0       55.9s

> [internal] load metadata for docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0:

---

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-wincred.exe": executable file not found in %PATH%, out: ```
ERROR: Service 'elasticsearch' failed to build

Has this repo worked to download ELK for others? I am cloning it on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Checks if the environment variables (system) are created in your operating system, in my case it has been solved.

my variables:

C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin
C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin

after creating them, restart the machine and test again

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since this is an English-only site, please edit your answer to remove the translations from your post.

Answer (score 0):

I had also this error when building image of logstash in Dockerfile. When I ran command `docker compose up` instead of `docker-compose up` it worked fine